# How do I sort a matrix via two indepedent columns?

Tags: python, columnsorting

I've recently started programming and I was tasked with finding the mean of different responses of a drug based on its dosage vs a placebo. I have a 4 column Excel file which is split into `Drug_1_Dosage`, `Drug_1_Response`, `Drug_2_Dosage`, `Drug_2_Response`, respectively.

I'm trying to have those values sorted in Jupyter notebook so that all instances where `Drug_1_Dosage` was `1-8` are sorted in an ascending manner for the response (there was more than 1 row with dosage 1 for example), while also doing the same for `Drug_2_Dosage` (but without affecting the first one).

I want to sort them so that I can calculate the mean later and express it as a two-column matrix.

So far I have this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = open('/Users/Envy/Desktop/Assingment Data.csv',"r")
table = pd.read_csv('/Users/Envy/Desktop/Assingment Data.csv')
drug_1_d = table.iloc[:,0]
drug_1_r = table.iloc[:,1]
drug_2_d = table.iloc[:,2]
drug_2_r = table.iloc[:,3]
```

Up to here everything is working fine as I can select each column independently. I tried the following for sorting to no success:

```
1) table = table.sort_values(['Dose drug 1', 'Dose drug 1'],ascending = True)
   table = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(table)
   table = table[table[:,0].argsort()]
2) table.sort(order=['f1'],axis=0)
3) table.sort_values(['Dose drug 1', 'Dose drug 2'], ascending=[True])
4) table = table.sort_values([:0,:2],ascending=[True])
```

EDIT:

Hey, I did some prodding around and this works with the above code

```
table = table.sort_values(['Dose drug 1', 'Dose drug 1'],ascending = True)
table = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(table) 
print(table)
```

But it returns

```
[[ 1 21  3 27]
 [ 1 19  7 10]
 [ 1 32  3 12]
 ...
 [ 8 18  4 24]
 [ 8  9  1 10]
 [ 8 13  2  9]]
```

Meaning that it only sorts by column 0 and not by column 2 also like I want it. Any idea how I can have both sorts independently?

Edit: After a lot of trial and error I now have the solution;

```
#Generate average response to dosage in 2 column matrix
table = pd.read_csv('Assingment Data.csv', sep=',')
final_means = pd.DataFrame()
# Grouping by Drug 1
final_means['Average Response Drug'] = table.groupby(['Dose drug 1'])['Response drug 1'].mean()
# Grouping by Drug 2
final_means['Average Response Placebo'] = table.groupby(['Dose drug 2'])['Response drug 2'].mean()
final_means.index.names = ['Dose']
print(final_means)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Pandas' [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation?
This allows you to reason per group without having to explicitly sort your table

Comment: Thank you so much! This with a bit of tinkering solved it. I added solution for future asks

Comment: @Energya Please submit your comment as a solution to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with Pandas' [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation? This allows you to reason per group without having to explicitly sort your table

A simple example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [0,0,1,1], 'col2': [1,2,3,4]})
>>> df
   col1  col2
0     0     1
1     0     2
2     1     3
3     1     4
>>> df.groupby('col1').mean()
      col2
col1
0      1.5
1      3.5
```

(Thanks to [@Sean-Pianka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4562156/sean-pianka) for suggesting I post my comment as a separate answer)